# Edmunds Auto API Output Value Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, wordpress

I've been trying to get the Edmunds Auto API to work in Wordpress for a while. This site's snippet is the closest I can get to a simple set of dropdown selects that let you select a year, make, model, style of a car (I did that with the below code).

http://wordpress-code-snippets.blogspot.com/2014/05/edmunds-vehicle-api-with-jquery.html

After the data is input I would like it to redirect to another page (action page), where the data can used to call the True Market Value (TMV) from the API, where it will be displayed on a screen.

I also need to email the visitor a snapshot of there car value using the Edmunds API as well. I am hoping to figure out how to integrate this with gravity forms for that, among other things (tracking).

Solving the problem of outputting the value on the next page is my main problem at the moment, so this question is just focusing on that issue.

I wasn't able to find a working solution in the documentation. I know it has to be something to do with the True Market Value (TMV) though.

http://developer.edmunds.com/faq.html

For the purpose of pulling in the Edmunds Auto API's general data into html selects, this code works perfect. It's just that it needs to be able to output the value somehow. I had to add the scripts in the footer when in Wordpress. Thats the only way I could get it to work.

```
<!--Form Details to display year/make/model in dropdown -->

<form method="POST" action="one123.php">
       <select id="ajYears" name="ajYears">
        </select>
         <select id="ajMakes" name="makes" disabled="disabled">
            <option>Select Make</option>
        </select>
        <select id="ajModels" name="models" disabled="disabled">
            <option>Select Model</option>
        </select>
        <select id="ajStyles" name="styles" disabled="disabled">
            <option>Select Trim</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>

<!--Script to fetch details from API-->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    jQuery.noConflict();
</script>

<!-- js code -->
<script>
    var protoCall = "https://";
    var host = "api.edmunds.com";

        // Make sure to change the API KEY
    var apiKey = "API KEY";
    var fmt = "json";
    var standardParams = "&fmt=" + fmt +  "&api_key=" + apiKey + "&callback=?";
    var $yearSelect = jQuery('#ajYears');
    var $makeSelect = jQuery('#ajMakes');
    var $modelSelect = jQuery('#ajModels');
    var $styleSelect = jQuery('#ajStyles');

    // lets bind some events on document.ready.
    jQuery(function(){

        $yearSelect.on('change', function() { getMakeModelsByYear()});
        $makeSelect.on('change', function() { enableModelDropdown() });
        $modelSelect.on('change', function() { getStyles() });

        // lets build the year drop down.
        ajEdmundsBuildYear();

    });

    // method to build the year drop down.
    function ajEdmundsBuildYear()
    {
        var baseYear = 1990,
            endYear = new Date().getFullYear();
        $yearSelect.empty();
        $yearSelect.append('<option value="-1">Select Year</option>');
        for(var yyyy=baseYear; yyyy<=endYear; yyyy++)
        {
            $yearSelect.append('<option value="' + yyyy + '">' + yyyy +'</option>');   
        }
    }

    // get the makes and models for a year in one go...
    function getMakeModelsByYear()
    {
        var year = $yearSelect.val(),
            endPoint = "/api/vehicle/v2/makes",
            view = "basic",
            options = "year=" + year + "&view=" + view + standardParams,
            postURL = protoCall + host + endPoint + "?" + options;
        jQuery.getJSON(postURL,
            function(data) {
                 // clear the make drop down... re add the first option... remove dsiabled attr.
                 $makeSelect.empty();
                 $makeSelect.append('<option value="-1">Select Make</option>');
                 $makeSelect.removeAttr('disabled');
                 $modelSelect.empty();
                 $modelSelect.append('<option value="-1">Select Model</option>');

                 // loop the makes... each make contains model... add the make in make drop down and models in model dd
                 jQuery.each(data.makes, function(i, val) {
                      make = data.makes[i];
                      $makeSelect.append('<option value="' + make.niceName + '">' + make.name + '</option>');
                      jQuery.each(make.models, function(x, val){   
                           model = make.models[x];
                           $modelSelect.append('<option make="' + make.niceName +'" value="' + model.niceName + '">' + model.name + '</option>');                 
                      });
                 });
            });
    }

    // since we already grabed the models...
    // now just matter of showing only the matching models for a make.
    function enableModelDropdown()
    {
        var make =  $makeSelect.val();
        $modelSelect.removeAttr('disabled');
        $modelSelect.find('option').not('[value="-1"]').hide();
        $modelSelect.find('option[make=' + make + ']').show();

    }

    // grab the styles... pretty much same as
    // getMakeModelsByYear()
    function getStyles()
    {
        var year = $yearSelect.val(),
            make = $makeSelect.val(),
            model = $modelSelect.val(),
            endPoint = "/api/vehicle/v2/" + make + "/" + model + "/" + year + "/styles",
            view = "basic",
            options = "view=" + view + standardParams,
            postURL = protoCall + host + endPoint + "?" +  options;
        jQuery.getJSON(postURL,
            function(data) {
                 $styleSelect.empty();
                 $styleSelect.removeAttr('disabled');
                 $styleSelect.append('<option value="-1">Select Style</option>');
                 jQuery.each(data.styles, function(i, val) {
                      style = data.styles[i];
                      $styleSelect.append("<option value='" + style.id + "'>" + style.name + "</option>");
                 });
            });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Here is an example of the ready-go-api that you really can't edit all that much.

http://codepen.io/rwmajux/pen/ozKdRP



Here is an example of it on their website (also doing something slightly different than what I need, but close).

http://www.edmunds.com/